# How to get last record of table in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

How to get last record of table in Codeigniter?

My table name is post I want to get last id or next id of last record in this table!

Answer (score 5):

```
//recommended don't use * from getting rows, insted of (*) please mention column names.

$row = $this->db->select("*")->limit(1)->order_by('id',"DESC")->get("table name")->row();
echo $row->id; //it will provide latest or last record id.
```

Answer (score 3):

Just sort your table data by id in descending order and pick the first row which will be the last inserted data. Example

```
$last_row=$this->db->select('id')->order_by('id',"desc")->limit(1)->get('post')->row();
```

$last_row will be initialized with last row

Answer (score 2):

```
$row = $query->last_row();// To get last record form the table
echo $row->id; // To print id of last record
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

Example:

```
function add_post($post_data){
   $this->db->trans_start();
   $this->db->insert('posts',$post_data);
   $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
   $this->db->trans_complete();
   return  $insert_id;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i want to get without insert_id() beacuse This function is used when using the Insert command !!!!

Comment: $query="Select max(id) from tpl_post";
$query=$this->db->query($query);
print_r($query->result());

Comment: No, `$this->db->insert_id()` returns the LAST INSERT property of your table regardless of how you inserted that data. This command will provide the last inserted id no matter what method of insertion you used.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("table name");
$this->db->limit(1);
$this->db->order_by('id',"DESC");
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function select(){
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("post");
    $this->db->order_by('id',"DESC"); //You can use limit before it. if u want last 3 or 4 entries from database.. 
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $category['rows'] = $query->num_rows();
        return $query->result();

    }
    else {
        return $query->result();

    }
    }// you can fetch your result in controller
```

Answer (score 0):

used limit in sql query and get last row.
like this `SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY your_auto_increment_field DESC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->db->get('table_name')->order_by('id','desc')->limit(1);
```

Hope this will work for you.