# how to search in database and return last row as array with codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

i want to search in two columns and select last record and send it as array to controller to show data

```
 public function show_data($post_code,$fname){
    $this->db->where('post_code',$post_code);
    $this->db->where('fname',$fname);

    $query=$this->db->get('customer');
    return $query->result_array();}
```

it finds my desire records  but i want to show last record, i used order_by(), limit() function but they don't work properly and affected my data entries in database. what's wrong? how can i correct it?
thank you

Comment: How exactly they won't work properly? How they can affect your data in database?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437881/how-to-get-last-record-of-table-in-codeigniter

Comment: when i use order_by("id","DESC ") and limit(1) it change two of my data entry and change their id.

Comment: saty i couldn't use it because i need to search first and then select last record

Comment: yes i check it and again i found error

Comment: What error you got??

Answer (score 0):

my solution is :

```
    public function show_data($post_code,$fname){
    $this->db->where('post_code',$post_code);
    $this->db->where('fname',$fname);
    $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query=$this->db->get('customer');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

thank you saty

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME=$COLUMN_NAME AND SECOND-COLUMN_NAME=$SECOND-COLUMN_NAME ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")->result();
return $query;
```

This will return you last row you created.